# Configure 'print' to display full struct fields

Tags: specman, e

I have nested structs defined as follows:

```
struct some_struct {
  some_field : uint;
  some_struct_field : some_other_struct;
  some_other_field : uint;
};

struct some_other_struct {
  some_field : uint;
  some_other_field : uint;
};
```

When I print an instance of *some_struct* using:

```
extend sys {
  run() is also {
    var some_struct : some_struct;
    gen some_struct;
    print some_struct;
  };
};
```

I get the following:

```
  some_struct = some_struct-@1: some_struct   of unit: sys 
    ----------------------------------------------  @test
0   some_field:                     3435783455
1   some_struct_field:              some_other_struct-@2
2   some_other_field:               2907638895
```

I'd like to see a detailed display of *some_struct_field*, which would show its sub-fields. Something like:

```
  some_struct = some_struct-@1: some_struct   of unit: sys 
    ----------------------------------------------  @test
0   some_field:                     3435783455
1   some_struct_field:              some_other_struct-@2
    0   some_field:                 1753518447
    1   some_other_field:           1744092907
2   some_other_field:               2907638895
```

I've tried using *print ... full=TRUE*, but that doesn't help either. I can't find any config knob for this behavior.

Do fields have any kind of attributes to customize how they're printed (like in UVM/SV field macros)?

I know there's a *do_print()* method that gets called when printing, that I can use to customize the displayed text, but I don't see how I could use it without re-implementing the whole print routine. If there were a way to capture the text that gets constructed, I could use that.

Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: I see there's a `get_printed_lines()` method, but I can't really use that inside `do_print()`, because it leads to an OS11 error (my guess, because of circular dependencies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it is not recommended to edit the do_print() method of any_struct to print the struct’s content recursively.
This is because some structs have pointers to their parent or another struct that is points back to this one (like driver and bfm),
And If you apply the modified do_print() method (by using ‘print’) to such a struct, will cause a never ending recursive printing
Which will most likely end in an OS 11 segmentation violation (due to stack overflow).

I would suggest creating a new method in any_struct which you will then use to print structs that do not have cyclic pointers
Anywhere in them.
My ides of such a method will make use of the reflection mechanism and will look like this:

```
extend any_struct{
printMe(s:string="") is{
    var fld_indx:uint=0;
    var printed_line:string;
    var get_struct: rf_struct = rf_manager.get_struct_of_instance(me); // get a reflection pointer to me
    var fields_in_struct : list of rf_field = get_struct.get_fields(); // get all my fields
    for each (strct_field) in fields_in_struct  do { 
        printed_line=append(s,fld_indx," ",strct_field.get_name());    // build the string that will display for this field
        out(str_pad(printed_line,40)," : ",strct_field.get_type().value_to_string(strct_field.get_value_unsafe(me)));
        var elem_type : rf_type = strct_field.get_type();              
        if (elem_type is a rf_struct) {                                // if the field is a struct, call this method recursively
            var st:any_struct= strct_field.get_value_unsafe(me).unsafe() ; 
            st.printMe(append(s,"    "));
        };
            fld_indx=fld_indx+1;
    };
 };
};
```

And you can then define a macro that will handle this in a manner more similar to how the print action looks like:

```
define <printr'action> "printr <exp>" as {
<exp>.printMe();
};
```

In the code, you can then write:

```
printr me; // usage example
```

Comment: It still requires redefining the print method completely, but it's cool that you gave me code that handles this nicely (padding and stuff). I'm going to build on this.

Comment: since the print action is used in many places, even in places where the developer forgets or is not aware that it exist in the code, it could be potentially dangerous to override the do_print method. this is why i offered to use a completely new method that needs to be used explicitly.
 i would like to hear about it you implementation when you are done :)